# Storage for bagger? Dimensions?

Tags: untagged

I’m going to be buying a bagger sometime soon for my radius s-series 60” mower. Does anyone know how much it’ll add to the width and length of the mower if I get one that has bags on the back? I was planning on putting a big net up around the red box in the photo that would be able to hold the bagger upright when it’s not attached to my mower. Does anyone think this will work. There’s around a foot and a half from the peak to the net if I were to put one up.

Ps. Don’t mind the shelving , those are going to be made to lift up when not in use. [image] [image]